# Bubble sort melhorado

Tags: c

Apesar de ter seguido o pseudocódigo corretamente, o programa não está ordenando o array corretamente. Por quê?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void bubbleSortM( int A[], int n ) 
{  
  int i,j,aux; 
  bool troca; 

  for(i=1; i<n; i++)
  troca = 0;

  for(j=n-1; j>=i ;j--) 
{  
if(A[j-1] > A[j]) 
  {    
 aux= A[j-1]; 
 A[j-1] = A[j]; 
 A[j] = aux; 
 troca = 1; 
   }
}
 if( !troca )
  {
return;
  }
  return;
}
void printVetor(int A[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
printf("%d ", A[i]);

}



int main()
{
int A[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

bubbleSortM(A, n);

printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
printVetor(A, n);
}
```

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudo com o erro deste programa.

Comment: Que erro? Edite sua pergunta para incluir o erro e aproveite para corrigir a formatação (selecione o trecho de código e aperte `<ctrl> + k`)

Comment: o programa não esta ordenando, da mesma forma que o vetor é inserido ele sai sem ordenar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, atente-se a identação do seu programa, que está horrível. Ela ajuda os outros (e também você mesmo) a entendê-lo. Se você tivesse feito isso, veria que falta um `{` depois do primeiro `for` e o `}` correspondente antes do fim da função, e que por causa disso, ele não faz nada do que você queria.

Além disso, é boa prática em C a declarar as variáveis somente quando serão usadas no menor escopo possível. C não é Pascal que exige que as variáveis sejam declaradas no início da função.

Um outro detalhe é `bits/stdc++.h` é um cabeçalho do C++, e não do C. Para o C, use `stdio.h` e `stdbool.h`.

E também há um `return` sobrando no final de `bubbleSortM` que é desnecessário, vez que é a última coisa da função.

Seu programa corrigido fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void bubbleSortM(int A[], int n) {  
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        bool troca = 0;

        for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--) {  
            if (A[j - 1] > A[j]) {
                int aux = A[j - 1];
                A[j - 1] = A[j];
                A[j] = aux;
                troca = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!troca) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void printVetor(int A[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    bubbleSortM(A, n);
    printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
    printVetor(A, n);
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/0guuWn)